# Update same ListView with new data in CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter, startactivityforresult

I am really stuck and have no idea what to do. I have looked into `startActivityForResult` and Content providers and I have no clue how to implement any of them for this app.

I am not seeing how to get the data from the database and update the `displayBottomList` using same `listview` so I don't have to redirect the user to a new layout/activity. Not sure if I can even call a new query and set that to a different cursor and switch between them. I have seen `swapCursor` but how does that work when using the same adapter?

I have a `ListView` that I want to refresh with new data from a web service call when the user clicks on a row within the list. I am using a `CursorAdapter`. I can get the data correctly `onClick` of the row.

Where I am stuck, is how do I update that `listView` to repopulate with the new info from the database/response without sending me to another Activity. I want the user to stay on the same screen but just update the `listView` with the new data.

Not sure how to get the adapter to notify the adapter to update and populate a new `ListView` when the `onClick` is in the adapter, but the `ListView` is being created in the `MainActivity`.

The Adapter for `BottomListView`, the one I want to update when a row is clicked.

```
public class BottomListViewAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private String mEmployeeNumber;
    private EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;

    public BottomListViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contact_cardview_layout, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(context);
        ViewHolder holder;
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvFirstName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personFirstName);
        holder.tvLastName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personLastName);
        holder.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personTitle);
        holder.mPeepPic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        holder.mDetailsButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fullDetailButton);
        holder.mCardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_screen_cardView);

        String mFirstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("First_name"));
        String mLastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Last_name"));
        String mTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Payroll_title"));
        String mThumbnail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ThumbnailData"));

        holder.tvFirstName.setText(mFirstName);
        holder.tvLastName.setText(mLastName);
        holder.tvTitle.setText(mTitle);

        if (mThumbnail != null) {
            byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(mThumbnail.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap parsedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
            holder.mPeepPic.setImageBitmap(parsedImage);
        } else {
            holder.mPeepPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_place_holder_adapter);
        }

        final int position = cursor.getPosition();

        holder.mDetailsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                String mEmployeeNumber = cursor.getString(1);
                String mEmail = cursor.getString(8);
                String mFirstName = cursor.getString(2);
                String mLastName = cursor.getString(3);
                String mPhoneMobile = cursor.getString(4);
                String mPhoneOffice = cursor.getString(5);
                String mCostCenter = cursor.getString(10);
                String mHasDirectReports = cursor.getString(7);
                String mTitle = cursor.getString(6);
                String mPic = cursor.getString(9);
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, EmployeeFullInfo.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("Employee_number", mEmployeeNumber);
                mIntent.putExtra("Email", mEmail);
                mIntent.putExtra("First_name", mFirstName);
                mIntent.putExtra("Last_name", mLastName);
                mIntent.putExtra("Phone_mobile", mPhoneMobile);
                mIntent.putExtra("Phone_office", mPhoneOffice);
                mIntent.putExtra("Cost_center_id", mCostCenter);
                mIntent.putExtra("Has_direct_reports", mHasDirectReports);
                mIntent.putExtra("Payroll_title", mTitle);
                mIntent.putExtra("ThumbnailData", mPic);
                mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                view.getContext().startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });

        holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                mEmployeeNumber = cursor.getString(1);
                Toast.makeText(context, mEmployeeNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                callNewDirectReport();
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvFirstName;
        TextView tvLastName;
        TextView tvTitle;
        ImageView mPeepPic;
        ImageButton mDetailsButton;
        CardView mCardView;
    }

    private void callNewDirectReport() {
        String mDirectReportUrl = "mURL";

        HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(mDirectReportUrl).newBuilder();
        urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("manager_employee_number", mEmployeeNumber);
        String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();


        OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    final String responseData = response.body().string();
                    final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
                    final XMLPullParserHandler parserHandler = new XMLPullParserHandler();
                    final ArrayList<Employee> employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) parserHandler.parse(stream);

                    for (Employee e : employees) {
                        dbHandler.addEmployee(e);
                    }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

My MainActivity that is calling the adapter

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private BottomListViewAdapter mBottomAdapter;
    private View mDividerView;
    EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;
    private int mStartingEmployeeID = mStartingID;
    private String table = "employees";
    private static final int LOADER_INTEGER = 1;
    private Cursor mBottomCursor, mTopCursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mDividerView = findViewById(R.id.divider);
        dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(getApplicationContext());
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mDividerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getXMLData();

        //GUI for seeing android SQLite Database in Chrome Dev Tools
        Stetho.InitializerBuilder inBuilder = Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this);
        inBuilder.enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this));
        Stetho.Initializer in = inBuilder.build();
        Stetho.initialize(in);
    }

    public void getXMLData() {
        OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(getString(R.string.API_FULL_URL))
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                final String responseData = response.body().string();
                final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
                final XMLPullParserHandler parserHandler = new XMLPullParserHandler();
                final ArrayList<Employee> employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) parserHandler.parse(stream);

                for (Employee e : employees) {
                    dbHandler.addEmployee(e);

                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mDividerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        displayTopList();
                        displayBottomList();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public void displayTopList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        mTopCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + "Employee_number" + "=" + mStartingEmployeeID, null);
        ListView mTopListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mTopList);
        TopListCursorAdapter topAdapter = new TopListCursorAdapter(this, mTopCursor);
        mTopListView.setAdapter(topAdapter);
    }

    public void displayBottomList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        mBottomCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " +
                "Employee_number" + "!=" + mStartingEmployeeID + " AND " +
                "Manager_employee_number" + "=" + mStartingEmployeeID + " ORDER BY " +
                "Last_name" + " ASC", null);

        ListView mBottomListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mDirectReportList);
        mBottomAdapter = new BottomListViewAdapter(this, mBottomCursor);
        mBottomListView.setAdapter(mBottomAdapter);
        mBottomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Comment: use volley library..one of the best way to repopulate your listview with the new info..!

Comment: Do you have any links that show this happening? Do not want to just switch my network call and just spend days trying to figure out how this is done.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: Still confused on how changing the way I am networking calling will help with me updating a listview onClick event within a CursorAdapter update the same list.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html here is the link for ur confusion...sorry for that..!

Comment: I am not seeing how using Volley over OkHttp3 is any different when it comes to trying to update the listView from within a CursorAdapter. I am already saving the data to a database, so not seeing why you are pushing Volley as the networking lib.

Comment: Right now when you click an item you only do the api call and then insert the new data in the database, the cursor on which the adapter is based will not auto update with the new items. So, in the callback(in onResponse()) from  callNewDirectReport()(after the for loop to add the new items in the database) you need to requery the database(with the same initial query you did in the displayBottomList() method) and then use the *swap(cursor)* method which will make the adapter use the new Cursor which will hold the new items as well.

Comment: @Luksprog Do I do the swap(cursor) in the main method or within the adapter?

Comment: @AdamGardner In the adapter, something like this: https://gist.github.com/luksprog/82752f9d947836030779404abdc67d54

Comment: @Luksprog I used the code you linked and now I get an "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." I know I need to runOnUiThread but I don't believe that is possible from the adapter.

Comment: @AdamGardner You can use runOnUiThread() from the adapter, you just need to keep a reference to the Context received in the constructor. I've updated my example https://gist.github.com/luksprog/82752f9d947836030779404abdc67d54

Comment: @Luksprog you are a life saver, can you please make your first comment and link to gist a Answer so I can accept it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your code in `callNewDirectReport()` makes an API request and stores the results in the database. This will not update the adapter to show the new items, instead you need to requery the database and get a newer Cursor. Below is an example of how you may do it:

```
public class BottomListViewAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private String mEmployeeNumber;
    private EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;
    private Activity activityRef;   

    public BottomListViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
        // keep a reference to the activity
        activityRef = (Activity) context;
    }
        
    //...

    private void callNewDirectReport() {
        //...
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    final String responseData = response.body().string();
                    final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
                    final XMLPullParserHandler parserHandler = new XMLPullParserHandler();
                    final ArrayList<Employee> employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) parserHandler.parse(stream);

                    for (Employee e : employees) {
                        dbHandler.addEmployee(e);
                    }
                    // the new items are in the database so requery the database to get a new fresher Cursor:
                    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
                    Cursor fresherCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " +
                        "Employee_number" + "!=" + mStartingEmployeeID + " AND " +
                        "Manager_employee_number" + "=" + mStartingEmployeeID + " ORDER BY " +
                        "Last_name" + " ASC", null);
                    //change the adapter's Cursor
                    activityRef.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            swapCursor(freshedCursor);
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use startActivityForResult to receive a callback from an activity, here you have a tutorial explaining how to use it: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

When you receive the callback in the onActivityResult, you can update your data and call notifyDatasetChanged.

You can't call code from an activity in another because activities are handled by android. Android could have killed the activity that you are trying to call and will just recreate it when necessary.

Comment: So I have to send the mCardView.setOnClickListener to a new activity, create a listview then pass that to the MainActivity?

Comment: No, besides calling startActivity, you call startActivityForResult passing and ID. The activity where you called startActivityForResult will receive in the onActivityResult the return. Read the link I attached in the response.

Comment: Confused on how to pass startActivityForResult on OnClickListener in my CursorAdapter to update the listView in the MainActivity. Seems like I need to get the response in mCardView.setOnClickListener, go to a new activity with startActivityforResult then in that activity do another one to pass back to mainAcitivty to have the listview update with new data from onclick?